# Idempotents and symmetries of Zn

Tags: graph-theory, ring-theory, soft-question, symmetry, idempotents

[Soft question out of curiosity]

While reading about idempotents of a ring, I used $\mathbb Z_n$ as a convenient example.  In visualizing the ring's structure, I was intrigued by strange symmetries in squared elements:

It seems that, in $\mathbb Z_n$, if n is even, the 'trajectories' of all squared elements are symmetrically arranged, and in all cases, the idempotent elements of the ring are symmetrically arranged.
[image: idempotents and trajectories in $\mathbb Z_6$]

[image]

(examples in $\mathbb Z_6$, black arrows indicate squaring, red indicate multiplication of two different elements)

this seems to be related to the fact that the ring is a direct sum of fields ($\mathbb Z_p$), as subrings... 
the symmetry being an artifact of the ring containing 'redundancies' from being a direct sum.

Does anyone know why this occurs or if there is anything to learn from these symmetries?  (if you know several idempotents, you can find the rest by symmetry.. I suppose).

Comment: Have you ever heard about [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)?

Comment: I kinda like those pictures!

Comment: Yes, yo.  The idempotent elements are quadratic residues in the subrings of $\mathbb Z_n$, congruent to 0 and 1, the trivial idempotents. So, all idempotents are generalizations of 0 and 1, as residues..